# Inconsistent regex matching in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have this code that prints matches found in two files using regex:

```
with open('ipCountry_list.txt','r') as csvfile1, open('city.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8" ) as file1:
    with open('unmatch.txt', 'a+') as file2:
        readCS = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter=';')
        reader = file1.readlines()
        for row in readCS:
            for line in reader:
                if all(re.findall(fr"\b{word}\b[^ ]", line, re.IGNORECASE) for word in row[:2]):
                    print(str(row) + line)
                    file2.write(str(row) + line)
                    break
                if all(re.findall(fr"\b{word}\b[^ ]", line, re.IGNORECASE) for word in row[:3]):
                    print(str(row) + line)
                    file2.write(str(row) + line)
                    break
```

Output:

```
['TH', 'BANGKOK']'TH~10~Bangkok'
['ES', 'VALENCIA']'ES~VC~Valencia'
['US', 'AZ', 'PHOENIX']'US~AZ~Aguila'
['JP', 'KASHIWA']'JP~12~Kashiwa'
[CZ;PRAGUE 4 - aaa]
```

If you see `['US', 'AZ', 'PHOENIX']'US~AZ~Aguila'` does not match.

`[CZ;PRAGUE 4 - aaa]` should be matching with `'CZ~10~Prague'` but it can't get a match.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, maybe my regex?

EDIT:

ipCountry_list.txt:

```
    TH;BANGKOK;aaa
    ES;VALENCIA;aaa
    US;AZ;PHOENIX;aaa
    JP;KASHIWA;aaa
    CZ;PRAGUE 4 - aaa;
    ZA;EAST LONDON;aaa
    GB;BRIDGWATER;aaa
    RU;MOSCOW;aaa
    GH;TEMA;aaa
```

city.txt:

```
    'TH~10~Bangkok'
    'ES~VC~Valencia'
    'US~AZ~Aguila'
    'US~AZ~Phoenix'
    'JP~12~Kashiwa'
    'GB~ENG~Bridgwater'
    'ZA~EC~East London'
    'RU~MOW~Moscow'
    'GH~AA~Tema'
    'CZ~10~Prague'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218084/discussion-on-question-by-sgt-string-match-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I suggest such a code as an answer:

```py
import csv
import re

with open('ipCountry_list.csv', 'r') as csvfile1, open('city.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file1:
    with open('unmatch.txt', 'a+') as file2:
        readCS = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter=';')
        reader = file1.readlines()
        # Fallback for the case when city.txt line
        # has no trailing newline. For example, it
        # can happen for the last line. But in the case
        # when every line has a newline, the code line
        # should be removed.
        reader = tuple(map(lambda line: line.strip('\n') + '\n', reader))
        for row in readCS:
            for line in reader:
                ready_row = row[:3] if len(row) > 3 else row[:2]
                ready_row = [re.sub(r'[ \d-]*aaa(?=$)', '', col)
                             if 'aaa' in col else col
                             for col in ready_row if col]
                if all(re.search(fr"\b{word}\b(?:[^ ]|$)", line,
                       re.IGNORECASE) for word in ready_row):
                    print(str(row) + line, end='')
                    file2.write(str(row) + line)
                    break
```

Comment: hi thanks for you input! its a valid solution. but its only giving me a result in where there is three matches  row matches. so US seems to be fixed. i thin you absolutely right about the second IF statement not being executed hence US is not coming up with the proper match

Comment: @sgt I have not understood the problem you have mentioned. For the minified files it solves the problems with `'CZ;PRAGUE 4 - aaa;'` and `'PHOENIX', 'aaa']'US~AZ~Aguila'`. The other matches are the same. Also the code repeating was reduced.

Comment: i have been testing the code. Unfortunately i replicated my question and yes your code works as it suppose and indeed is the perfect answer for the question. BUT somehow. when i use my original file, it seems to only print when 3 rows are matching. so matches like US are indeed working, but it seem to not pick up anything else

Comment: @sgt then you need to attach the original files, if it's possible.

Comment: Hi splitter thank you for this, unfortunately its not possible to upload the files. I have marked you answer as correct because indeed it is! thank you!